# Htaccess "410 GONE" for all pages and redirect to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to let google and other bots that my old web pages are removed forever (410 GONE) and redirect to main page `index.php` which includes the simple text with link tonew domain `"The site is moved to new domain www.new_domain.com"`

So, request to all removed pages like:

```
www.old_domain.com/about.php
www.old_domain.com/view.php?id=123
```

should be sent to `www.old_domain.com/index.php`, with the return code 410 to Google i.e. "all pages except index.php are gone forever"

What is the best way to achieve this?

1. using PHP code `header( "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone" );` inserted in index.php file

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?PHP    
    header( "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone" );
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <title>www.old_domain.com</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    The site is moved to <a href="https://www.new_domain.com/" 
    title="https://www.new_domain.com/">https://www.new_domain.com/</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. Or htaccess method:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.old_domain.com.com/? [G,L]
```

Which seems doesn't work,since redirects to Apache 410 error page and visitors do not see where the new site is moved from index.php.

Note: I do not want to use `301` redirects to the new domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "410 Gone" status is an error status, not a redirect.   All redirect statuses are in the 300s.  You **cannot** serve a 410 status AND redirect at the same time. The HTTP spec does not allow that.

What you can do instead is set your custom page for the "gone" status:

```sh
ErrorDocument 410 /410-gone.html
```

And place your message in that file.   Then Apache will serve that message for all the "gone" requests and no redirects are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !index\.php - [R=410,L]
```

Just replace `olddomain.com` with your domain name in the condition pattern above.

Comment: ++ though `/index.php` in target won't do anything. It can be just `-`

Comment: @Anubhava good point . I will edit the line.